# Is there a public ROS matster available?

Tags: ros, rosmaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,
Since in our lab, we can not communicate with socket between two computer, is there a public ROS master available? Thus we can use two or more computer in my lab to connect this public ros MASTER,then to communicate with ros message or service.
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://pulbic:11311
Best regards.
Zhenli

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54477/is-there-a-public-ros-matster-available?/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know: No.

It wouldn't also be quite usable, because when everyone uses the same public master, you will have a lot of conflicts.

In addition it will also not solve your problem. The ROS master doesn't route anything. It just provides a central lookup, so nodes/topics/services can find themselves. The connections are made directly between nodes and do not go over the master.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4